# To find a unique from a column with dtype =object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

[image: please check the code i am doing]Sample data:

[image]

`test_Unique` is output file which is giving `8,8 2` time which I don't want, as I want only unique values and drop duplicates but `8,8` appears `2` time. Same for `6,7`

> the dtype for my sample data is object  'string' the sample data is in
>   column name final_Unique in my dataframe  final_task

```
8,8
6,7
7,7
7,6
2,12
12,3
3,4
4,12
12,12
14,14
1,1
1,12
12,2
2,2
2,4
6,8
8,8
```

Code I am trying is this :

```
final_task['test_Unique']=final_task['final_Unique'].drop_duplicates()
```

but i am not getting the perfect output what is the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over each row, then split the string, then find unique and again join them. Then you can run `drop_duplicates()` on the new series.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("final_task.csv")

df['final_Unique'].apply(lambda x: ",".join(map(str,sorted(map(int,x.split(',')))))).drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: I have to get 8,8 as a pair not a 8

Comment: @Quicklearner I misunderstood your question. Anyway, I have an updated answer. Please check.

Comment: Series([], Name: new_values, dtype: object) i am getting this and nothing in both my values and new values  column..

Comment: @Quicklearner I’m not sure what wrong you are doing. Can you share snapshot ?

Comment: @Quicklearner Also copy paste my whole code, and share response?

Comment: is it becuase of string type data in final_unique column

Comment: @Quicklearner no not due to string type. Please copy paste my code in your environment as it is and share result.

Comment: i have uploaded an image and edited the code section

Comment: in my question i have uploaded

Comment: @Quicklearner you have not passed input correctly. Copy my input list and then try. Your input is not a list. Even you need to use only last 2 lines of my solution in your code not others.

Comment: @Quicklearner you need to understand what I have done then refer that understanding in your code. For that run while my code directly understand it then modify your codes.

Comment: now i am getting this  error : 'int' object has no attribute 'split' i do understand the code

Comment: Have you copied inp variable as it is from my code? This code is running on my machine. Anyway, I have given theoretically explaination in my answer. Pls do that in your way to reach solution.

Comment: i have to use it on a dataframe column not on a hard coded input

Comment: That can be done once you verify this. It’s very simple use only last 2 lines of my solution, they also working on data frame column. As I don’t have your data frame so I’m creating one feom your data.

Comment: @Quicklearner Share your CSV or DataFrame, then I can able to give you an exact solution which will work directly on your side.

Comment: how can i share?

Comment: share your email id, I will mail you.

Comment: pls, check email.